# Building a DOS/Win95/98 computer from scratch

Tags: ms-dos, gaming, windows-95, windows-98

I'd like to build a DOS/Win95/98 computer in order to play old PC games I have without emulation.

Here are a few games I'd like to run:

- Teranova: Strike Force Centauri;
- System Shock 1 and 2;
- Half-Life;
- Baldur's Gate;
- Myst;
- Syndicate and Syndicate Wars;
- Shogo;
- Command and Conquer: Red Alert...

The problem is that good documentation on old components seems rare. So I have a few question:

- Should I build a Win95 or Win98 computer in order to also play DOS games (System Shock, Teranova...)? I know some DOS games plays too fast on systems that are too powefull, should I just build a DOS only computer?
- Should I seek an AT or an ATX motherboard, and which models and specs are the best?
- What processors specs should I aim for?
- What graphics card specs should I look out for (I know the Voodoo series is great, but they are way too much expensive);
- What sound cards specs should I aim for (I've allways heard that the Soundblasters cards would be the best)?

Can anyone help me with tihs please?

If anyone knows any detailled documentation on the required the required specs for this era of PC gaming, please tell me.

Comment: I think this question is a little broad.  Please ask only one question per post.

Comment: Emulation's your best bet; you can customise the hardware and speed on the fly. However, this question is *way* too broad. You are asking at least six questions in one. Please (re-)read [ask], then post them separately.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I'd nearly finished an answer — any chance you'd reconsider? The issue is that many of the sub-questions here are inter-related, so splitting the question up would produce questions which aren't as useful...

Comment: @StephenKitt Ok, I'll reopen it.

Comment: Also, emulation is nice for most DOS games, but there are quite a few games where you need consistency which current emulators can't provide; *e.g.* flight simulators, the X-Wing series etc. can't be played properly in DOSBox. Some of the harder jumping puzzles in Tomb Raider are also very hard to get right in DOSBox, but easy on a DOS PC with a decent controller.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 just because someone has an answer to the question doesn't make it any less broad.  Reopening this question encourages users to continue to ask and answer questions that are too broad.

Comment: @JAL I agree, but reading my answer may help to understand how it could be split ;-).

Comment: @StephenKitt Should I close it again then?

Comment: @JAL If the system lets you you can vtc again. If not, you can flag tc.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I'd just let the vote play out... It's not as if there's so much activity on the site that admin hammers are really necessary :-/.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I can no longer vote to close the question because any user can only [vote to close once per question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10583/242209).  I also cannot flag to close because I have the Cast Close And Reopen Votes privilege.

Comment: @JAL It's gone back into the queue now.

Comment: At least give some consideration to virtualization. KVM (on Linux) can perfectly well provide a VM with a virtual Pentium CPU, contemporary i440FX chipset, Cirrus 54xx video, PS/2 keyboard and mouse, IDE virtual hard drives, virtual (or even physical) floppies, and SoundBlaster 16. This can also be done (with somewhat greater difficulty, and reduced performance) with QEMU on Windows. A quick survey of the Internet shows people have gotten things like System Shock 1 to run in this environment.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Virtualisation works quite well for many games, but there are still quite a few which don't run smoothly enough to play well (whether under virtualisation or with non-cycle-accurate emulators like DOSBox). Admittedly the list given in the question should work well under a hypervisor... [PCem](http://pcem-emulator.co.uk/) is worth a look, it is a more accurate emulator and supports gaming niceties such as 3Dfx emulation.

Comment: If going the AT route, mind that installing an AT power supply (unless you start with a complete case) involves installing a power switch that is directly connected to live mains. Usually comes pre-attached on a cable and reasonably insulated, but if you do not feel up to judging safety of mains connected circuitry, have help. Be safe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a rather broad question, but the answers are inter-related so here goes.

> Should I build a Win95 or Win98 computer in order to also play DOS games (System Shock, Teranova...)?

This was common in the late 90s: PCs mostly ran Windows 95 or 98 then, but still ran DOS games too.

> I know some DOS games plays too fast on systems that are too powefull, should I just build a DOS only computer?

That's true of older DOS games, but the games you've listed work well on faster computers. In fact the later DOS games (published after Windows 95 was released) tend to be quite CPU-hungry...

> Should I seek an AT or an ATX motherboard, and which models and specs are the best?

This is related to the CPU and graphics card you end up choosing. If you're getting a Pentium II, Athlon or later CPU, you'll find more ATX motherboards than AT motherboards. If you're aiming for a classic Pentium or Pentium MMX (socket 7), you'll find more AT motherboards.

In any case, if you can get an ATX motherboard, it will be easier to build a working system nowadays: AT power-supplies are harder to find, AT keyboards too...

> What processors specs should I aim for?

I would aim for something typical for the very end of the 90s, *e.g.* a Pentium II around 500MHz. (In 2000 I had a 750MHz Athlon running Windows 98.) For a pure DOS system I prefer classic Pentiums, but Windows 95/98 games tend to need faster processors.

> What graphics card specs should I look out for (I know the Voodoo series is great, but they are way too much expensive);

The ideal combination for DOS games is an S3 card of some sort (S3 Trio64 for example) along with a Voodoo 2.

For Windows 95/98 you really want a card that can run DirectX well; early GeForce cards were very good. Their VBE support under DOS is good too, so you could use that for DOS games as well. Using a GeForce means getting a motherboard with good AGP support, which pretty much means a 440BX board and a Pentium II or III. (Just make sure the board has ISA slots too, for the sound card.)

> What sound cards specs should I aim for (I've always heard that the Soundblasters cards would be the best)?

For DOS, get an **ISA** Soundblaster. Soundblaster 16 cards are cheap and plentiful, and the plug-and-play models are easy to set up. These will also work well in Windows.

PCI sound cards work fine in Windows but tend to cause problems with DOS games.

Picking a sound card is probably the hardest part in all this; check out [the Doom E1M1 comparison](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXFYWJ7dbz0) (and [part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_TsL0HyVq4g)), [LGR's evolution of PC audio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a324ykKV-7Y), or [Anatoly Shashkin's tweets which often touch on this](https://twitter.com/dosnostalgic).